# Vue and cypress having issues raising in time for tests

Tags: vue.js, cypress

Running a vue e2e test inside a Jenkins container and cypress base (node 16) container.

We successfully yarn install and lint our stack in the docker container; when we run this command from our package.json

```
"test:e2e:ci": "vue-cli-service test:e2e --mode dev --headless --config video=false",
```

but we're getting this error in jenkins

```
Error: Command failed: /buildp/jenkins/workspace/project/app/node_modules/cypress/bin/cypress run --config baseUrl=https://localhost:3000/,video=false --headless

    at makeError (/buildp/jenkins/workspace/project/app/node_modules/@vue/cli-shared-utils/node_modules/execa/index.js:174:9)

    at /buildp/jenkins/workspace/project/app/node_modules/@vue/cli-shared-utils/node_modules/execa/index.js:278:16

    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)

    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)

error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

a few lines later, the service is running seems to be running, and our tests start correctly passing or failing.

It seems like vue-cli-server is taking a while to get raised before the tests run; anyway, can we remedy that issue?

https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/package/cypress